# Looping a proc transpose through multiple data ranges SAS

Tags: loops, sas, transpose

I am trying to transpose a sequence of ranges from an excel file into SAS. The excel file looks something like this:

```
            31 Dec   01Jan   02Jan   03Jan   04Jan  
 Book id1    23       24      35      43      98  
 Book id2     3       4       5       4       1  

 (few blank rows in between)  

             05Jan   06Jan   07Jan   08Jan   09Jan  
 Book id1    14      100      30     23      58  
 Book id2    2       7        3      8       6  


 (and it repeats..)
```

My final output should have a first column for the date and then two additional columns for the book Ids:

```
  Date    Book id1    Book id2
  31 Dec   23           3
  01Jan    24           4
  02Jan    35           5
  03Jan    43           4
  04Jan    98           1
  05Jan    14           2
  06Jan    100          7
  07Jan    30           3
  08Jan    23           8
  09Jan    58           6
```

In this particular case I am asking for a simpler method to:

1. Either import and transpose each range of data and replacing the data range with macro variables to separately import and transpose each individual range
2. Or to import the whole datafile first and then to create a loop that
   transposes each range of data

Code I used for a simple import and transpose of a specific data range:

```
           proc import datafile="&input./have.xlsx"  
                     out=want  
                     dbms=xlsx  replace;  
                     range="Data$A3:F5" ;  
                     run;  

                     proc transpose data=want  
                            out=want_transposed  
               name=date;  
               id A;  
                     run;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post anything you've tried so far to solve this problem. Note that i'm expecting that you can already import the file and have a SAS data set. If not, you should start with that as your problem and get that worked out first. If you do have your data in and don't know where to start for a transpose try these tutorials: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long-using-a-data-step/

Answer (score 0):

A data row that is split over several segments or blocks of rows in an Excel file can be imported raw into SAS and then processed into a categorical form using a DATA Step.

In this example sample data is put into a text file and imported such that the column names are generic VAR-1 ... VAR-*n*.  The generic import is then processed across each row, outputting one SAS data set row per import cell.

The *column names* in each segment are retained within a temporary array an updated whenever a blank book id is encountered.

```
* mock data;
filename demo "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))\demo.txt";

data _null_;
  input;
  file demo;
  put _infile_;
datalines;
        .,    31Dec,   01Jan,   02Jan,   03Jan,   04Jan  
 Book_id1,    23   ,   24   ,   35   ,   43   ,   98  
 Book_id2,     3   ,   4    ,   5    ,   4    ,   1  

        .,    05Jan,   06Jan,   07Jan,  08Jan,   09Jan  
 Book_id1,    14   ,   100  ,   30   ,  23   ,   58  
 Book_id2,    2    ,   7    ,   3    ,  8    ,   6  
run;

* mock import;
proc import replace out=work.haveraw file=demo dbms=csv;
  getnames = no;
  datarow = 1;
run;

ods listing;
proc print data=haveraw;
run;
```

When Excel import is be made to look like this:

```
Obs    VAR1        VAR2     VAR3     VAR4     VAR5     VAR6

 1                 31Dec    01Jan    02Jan    03Jan    04Jan
 2     Book_id1    23       24       35       43       98
 3     Book_id2    3        4        5        4        1
 4
 5                 05Jan    06Jan    07Jan    08Jan    09Jan
 6     Book_id1    14       100      30       23       58
 7     Book_id2    2        7        3        8        6
```

It can be processed in a transposing way, outputting only the name value pairs corresponding to a original cell.

```
data have (keep=bookid date value);
  set haveraw;

  array dates(1000) $12 _temporary_ ;
  array vars var:;

  if missing(var1) then do;
    do index = 2 by 1 while (index <= dim(vars));
      if not missing(vars(index)) then 
        dates(index) = put(index-1,z3.) || '_' || vars(index);  * adjust as you see fit;
      else 
        dates(index) = '';
    end;
  end;
  else do;
    bookid = var1;
    do index = 2 by 1 while (index <= dim(vars));
      date = dates(index);
      value = input(vars(index),??best12.);
      output;
    end;
  end;    
run;
```